# how create a animation slide_up?

Tags: android

I want when the activity began.
Started to become an animation Slide_up. Like program CM
[image]

So for this I wrote the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fff"
 >
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/slide_up"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#0b2842" />  


<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linear_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:background="#ffff"
android:padding="@dimen/padding"
android:visibility="gone"
android:orientation="vertical"
   >

 </LinearLayout>
```

anim_slide_up.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
 >  
   <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-66%p"   android:duration="1000"
  />
</set>
```

SlideUpActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_up);
    startAnim();

 }

  public void startAnim()
{
  anim_slide_up.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

            root.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            
        }
    });
 linear_slide_up.startAnimation(anim_slide_up);

 }
```

But it was not something that I really want.
Who is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Object Animator

ObjectAnimator mover = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mainView, "translationY", viewHeight);
mover.setDuration(300);
mover.start();

Comment: I get height Screen and set( 2/3 Height) for ObjectAnimator .thanks